# How to convert a str like this format '2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00' to datetime in python?

Tags: python, string, datetime

I need convert a set of strings that is in this format "2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00".

I try use this:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime("2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%Z')
```

But i have this  output:

```
>> ValueError: time data '2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%Z'
```

How can i convert this date?

Comment: The format is pretty much ISO8601, so you can use `datetime.fromisoformat`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to include the `+` of the timezone, and it's a lowercase `z`

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime("2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')

print(date)
```